# Cannot find module '../request' error using mock in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a test file that has this line

```
jest.mock('../request');
```

but it seems couldn't find my **mocks** folder and it's request file. My folder structure as below

[image]

I followed the example of jest here https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/async

Any clue what's wrong?

Answer (score 9):

The path in `jest.mock` needs to be the relative path from your test to the module you want to mock (`request.js`) and the `__mocks__` folder needs to be in the folder where the original `request.js` file is in. From your screenshot its hard to see if its like this. Also your test dont show the `jest.mock('../request');` line.

Comment: mocks need to be in request.js? What does that means? request.js is just my mock file right? what's so special about that?

Comment: No it must be in the same *folder* as `request.js`

Comment: look at this file structure https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/async